# CAPTCHA fails shows alert but form submitting automatically how to stop this

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

This is basic registration module in this i added captcha works

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form-register" role="form" id="register-form">
                    <div>
                        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User name"> 
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" > 
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input name="password" id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"> 
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <input name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password"> 
                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div>
       <div>
                    <td id="imgparent">
    <div id="imgdiv">
    <img id="img" src="captcha.php">
    </div>
    <img id="reload" src="images/reload.png">

    <input id="captcha1" name="captcha" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter captcha">
    </td>
    </tr>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
                    </div> 
                    <button class="btn btn-block bt-login" id="button" type="submit">Sign Up</button>

                    <h4 class="text-center login-txt-center">Alternatively, you can log in using:</h4>

                    <a class="btn btn-default facebook_rnd" href="login.php?type=facebook"> <i class="fa fa-facebook modal-icons-rnd"></i> </a>  
                    <a class="btn btn-default google_rnd" href="login.php?type=google"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus modal-icons-rnd"></i> </a>  

                </form>
```

it is register.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#register-form").validate({
        submitHandler : function(e) {
            $(form).submit();
        },
        rules : {
            name : {
                required : true
            },
            email : {
                required : true,
                email: true,
                remote: {
                    url: "check-email.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        email: function() {
                            return $( "#email" ).val();
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            password : {
                required : true
            },
            confirm_password : {
                required : true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            }
        },
        messages : {
            name : {
                required : "Please enter name"
            },
            email : {
                required : "Please enter email",
                remote : "Email already exists"
            },
            password : {
                required : "Please enter password"
            },
            confirm_password : {
                required : "Please enter confirm password",
                equalTo: "Password and confirm password doesn't match"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
             $(element).closest('div').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
             $(element).closest('div').find('.help-block').html('');
        }
    });


});
```

it is for CAPTCHA js

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
// Change CAPTCHA on each click or on refreshing page.
$("#reload").click(function() {
$("#img").remove();
$('<img id="img" src="captcha.php" />').appendTo("#imgdiv");
});
// Validation Function
$('#button').click(function() {
var name = $("#username1").val();
var email = $("#email1").val();
var captcha = $("#captcha1").val();
if (name == '' || email == '' || captcha == '') {

} else {
// Validating CAPTCHA with user input text.
var dataString = 'captcha=' + captcha;
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "verify.php",
data: dataString,
success: function(html) {

      if ($.trim(captcha) == '2') {
                        alert('Entered code is wrong');
                        reloadCaptcha();
                        return false;
                    }
                    validated = true;
                    $("#button").submit();

alert(html);
}
});
}
});
});
```

here when all validation are works fine but if the CAPTCHA is wrong then also it submitting he form why?>>

how to stop when **CAPTCHA** is worng return to form ??

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here is never what you want to be doing with Captcha.

The reason Captcha exists is to prevent malicious form submissions, meaning that you're not supposed to be able to submit any data to the server without a valid Captcha. However, what you're doing is validating the Captcha in Javascript, then submitting the form.

There is nothing stopping someone from manually calling $('#button').submit() to push whatever data they like to the server. The Captcha is essentially useless; it's like a door with no walls around it.

You'll need to re-implement your Captcha solution to do the validation on the server side, wherever your form is submitting to. First validate the Captcha, then process the form submission.

You could use something like this:

```
session_start();
if($_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['<insert Captcha Session key here>']) { /* invalid captcha */ }
```